# How to localize ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, internationalization

I installed ArcGIS 10.2.2 on my laptop and try to localize the ArcMap component to my native language. I used programs like (Lingobit localizer and SDL passolo) to translate resource strings in the file ArcMap.exe but no effect occurred on ArcMap interface. I noticed that some DLLs related to UI should be translated too, but there is a huge number of them.

Anybody can direct me to know which Files (DLLs) should I translate to make ArcMap user interface in my language?

Answer (score 1):

If your language is on this list you can dopwnload you language package from ESRI.  http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/18/metaid/1723

Comment: Thanks @cbunn, but no it's not included. Furthermore, I need 10.2.2 localization.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.2 is currently supported in multiple languages, which you can access from the [My Esri portal.](https://my.esri.com)

[image]

Since your language is not here, you can contact your [local Esri distributor](http://www.esri.com/about-esri/offices). From my experience, most of the countries have local Esri distributors localizing the software into the local language. Even if they don't work with the Esri on streamlining the localization workflow, most of those reps will have some certain language pack which you will be able to install on top of the ArcGIS installation.

If your Esri local distributor doesn't provide one, you will not be able to localize the software solely on your own. This would require partly reverse engineering the software which you cannot do without violating the license agreement. Ask local Esri rep if they have some parts of the documentation translated, such as the basics chapters or some brochures which will help you get started (or share with your end users).

Checking the web help in another language is rather easy now (only for the languages officially supported):

```
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000004s000000
```

Replace the `en` with another language code, such as `fr` to get the French help, `de` for German, `es` for Spanish and so forth.

Training in your language can also boost understanding of the product and maybe you won't need to install the language pack for you/your users. Check your local Esri web site to see what kind of training is offered.

**I am a strong advocate of having any software (including ArcGIS) installed in English**, so think twice if you really need a localized version. If you get an error, you get in your language as well as the button/tools/options names. It will be very hard to search the Internet with this error message and using the localized names of the UI elements. The documentation is translated which means it is in many cases not as good as English one and one might find it easier to read the English version to understand a certain concept. Unless there are some strong reasons, stick with the English version of ArcGIS and this will broad the access to the resources and the help.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I searched `My Esri portal` for available localization but found nothing. Where should I find them?

Comment: @lio, as I outlined in my answer, you should contact your local Esri distributor.

Comment: I purchased my ArcGIS DVDs from another country (Holland), and now I'm in a place out of the technology's coverage area. I'll try to contact Esri directly.